# How to update an integer value in an SQL record?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm pretty new to SQL and the Sqlite3 module and I want to edit the timestamps of all the records in my DB randomly.

```
import sqlite3
from time import time
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = sqlite3.Cursor(conn)

ts_new = round(time())
ts_old = 1537828957
difference = ts_new - ts_old

for i in range(1,309):

    #getting a new, random timestamp
    new_ts = ts_old + random.randint(0, difference)

    t = (new_ts, i)
    c.executemany("UPDATE questions SET timestamp = (?) WHERE rowid = (?)", t)

#conn.commit()
```

When run, I get a  `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`.

To add the `timestamp` value originally I set `t` to a tuple and the current UNIX timestamp as the first value of a it e.g `(1537828957, )`. Is this error displaying because I've used two `(?)` unlike the single one I used in the statement to add the timestamps to begin with?

Comment: What line is the error from?

Comment: And what type is `timestamp`? Can you show us `.schema questions`?

Comment: from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany): `seq_of_parameters` -- parameter sequences or mappings, i.e. in your case you should pass `[t]` instead of just `t` or use `sqlite3.Cursor.execute` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`executemany`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) instead of [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). `executemany` takes an iterator of tuples and executes the query for each tuple.

You want to use `execute` instead, it executes the query once using your `tuple`.

```
c.execute('UPDATE questions SET timestamp = (?) where rowid = (?)', t)
```